# Could not transfer artifact org.gs4tr.projectdirector.adaptors:globallink-connect-api:jar:4.18.2 from/to nexus

Tags: java, maven, liferay, jenkins-pipeline, nexus

I have tried to build a liferay application by using maven integration but it fails to deploy the JAR mentioned below, except for this jar remaining jars uploaded normally.

**Error log**

```
[INFO] Final Memory: 74M/1623M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.7:deploy (default-deploy) on project globallink-connect-api: Failed to deploy artifacts: Could not transfer artifact org.gs4tr.projectdirector.adaptors:globallink-connect-api:jar:4.18.2 from/to nexus (http://repo8.corp.net/nexus/content/repositories/releases): Access denied to: http://repo8.core.corp.net/nexus/content/repositories/releases/org/gtr/projectdirector/adaptors/globallink-connect-api/4.18.2/globallink-connect-api-4.18.2.jar, ReasonPhrase: Forbidden. -> [Help 1]
```

Comment: It says access denied.  Can you download it manually through your webbrowser or from that server?  If not you probably lack permissions.  If so, I suspect maven or NXRM needs the right credentials.

Comment: Thanks for your response! , i am able to download it manually from webbrowser ,agian explain the problem, it only failed to upload particular globallink-connect-api-4.18.2.jar except this remaining is uploaded.

Answer (score 0):

Out of the box, Nexus Repository Manager disables redeploy of released components in most (if not all) repository types, including Maven.  This is because the assumption is once released a component is that version, not that it will be further edited.  This is also for the protection of the users, otherwise it's impossible to tell who has what version of what.

Since it was noted in commentary that you are able to download the component, it is already in your repository manager and without more logs my assumption is that it's redeploy denial that's forbidden.

If the assumption is correct and you want to proceed despite this caution it can be disabled. See https://help.sonatype.com/display/NXRM3/Repository+Management#RepositoryManagement-ManagingRepositoriesandRepositoryGroups for details about "Deployment policy".  That's for NXRM3, but NXRM2 has a similar feature if you're using that version.